# How to customize progress bar including text in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin

I am having an idea to make a progress bar that contains properties like the attached image. However I don't know how to implement xaml UI so that it is perfect. Ask for help. Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use StepProgressBar.

Install from NuGet: Syncfusion.Xamarin.SfProgressBar

Code:

```
<progressBar:SfStepProgressBar Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
        <progressBar:StepView PrimaryText="10%" SecondaryText="0K" Status="InProgress"/>
        <progressBar:StepView PrimaryText="11%" SecondaryText="100K" Status="NotStarted"/>
        <progressBar:StepView PrimaryText="12%" SecondaryText="300K" Status="NotStarted"/>
        <progressBar:StepView PrimaryText="13%" SecondaryText="500K" Status="NotStarted"/>
        <progressBar:StepView PrimaryText="14%" SecondaryText="900K" Status="NotStarted"/>
        <progressBar:StepView PrimaryText="15%" SecondaryText="1000K" Status="NotStarted"/>
    </progressBar:SfStepProgressBar>
```

Comment: Syncfusion is only trialed for 30 days. Do you have any other solution?

Comment: It needs to create your own custom progressbar. I need some time and would feedback ASAP.

Comment: Thank you. I got the idea right here, you can watch it, it's not perfect :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69941006/how-to-set-progressbar-in-xamarin