# How to set ProgressBar in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69881740/how-to-customize-progress-bar-including-text-in-xamarin/) about customizing ProgressBar. However I am not using Syncfusion. Here is my idea, it seems not perfect =]]]]]

```
<StackLayout Padding="12,0" Margin="0,0,0,35">
    <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="#fff" Padding="0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!--group-->
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,0,-2" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
            <Label Text="0 K" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontSize="12" />
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
            <Frame HasShadow="False" Padding="0" CornerRadius="30" WidthRequest="10" HeightRequest="10" BackgroundColor="Red"></Frame>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,-2,0,0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
            <Label Text="10%" TextColor="Red" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontSize="13" />
        </Grid>
        <!--end group-->
        <!--group-->
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,0,-2" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
            <Label Text="10 K" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontSize="12" />
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
            <Frame HasShadow="False" Padding="0" CornerRadius="30" WidthRequest="10" HeightRequest="10" BackgroundColor="#ddd"></Frame>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,-2,0,0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
            <Label Text="11%" TextColor="Red" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontSize="13" />
        </Grid>
        <!--end group-->
        <!--group-->
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Margin="0,0,0,-2" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
            <Label Text="200 K" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontSize="12" />
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
            <Frame HasShadow="False" Padding="0" CornerRadius="30" WidthRequest="10" HeightRequest="10" BackgroundColor="#ddd"></Frame>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Margin="0,-2,0,0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
            <Label Text="12%" TextColor="Red" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontSize="13" />
        </Grid>
        <!--end group-->
        <!--group-->
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Margin="0,0,0,-2" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
            <Label Text="300 K" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontSize="12" />
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
            <Frame HasShadow="False" Padding="0" CornerRadius="30" WidthRequest="10" HeightRequest="10" BackgroundColor="#ddd"></Frame>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" Margin="0,-2,0,0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
            <Label Text="12%" TextColor="Red" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontSize="13" />
        </Grid>
        <!--end group-->
        <!--group-->
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" Margin="0,0,0,-2" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
            <Label Text="400 K" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontSize="12" />
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
            <Frame HasShadow="False" Padding="0" CornerRadius="30" WidthRequest="10" HeightRequest="10" BackgroundColor="#ddd"></Frame>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="4" Margin="0,-2,0,0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
            <Label Text="12%" TextColor="Red" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontSize="13" />
        </Grid>
        <!--end group-->
        <!--group-->
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="5" Margin="0,0,0,-2" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
            <Label Text="500 K" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontSize="12" />
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="5" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
            <Frame HasShadow="False" Padding="0" CornerRadius="30" WidthRequest="10" HeightRequest="10" BackgroundColor="#ddd"></Frame>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="5" Margin="0,-2,0,0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
            <Label Text="12%" TextColor="Red" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontSize="13" />
        </Grid>
        <!--end group-->
    </Grid>

    <ProgressBar Margin="35,-37.5,35,0" ProgressColor="#ddd" HeightRequest="3" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" x:Name="progressbar"/>
</StackLayout>
```

And this is the result:

[image]

I have 2 questions:

1. How is the ProgressBar below the red dot I circled in the image above?
2. Inside .xaml.cs how can i set ProgressTo for ProgressBar. Here is how I set it up. However it doesn't work:

```
private async void Progress()
{
    progressbar.Progress = 10000;
    float progress = 2000;
    await progressbar.ProgressTo(progress, 500, Easing.Linear);
}
```

Please help any solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. Because your `ProgressBar` is the last element in your `StackLayout`, it will be drawn on **TOP** of the previous controls
2. From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/progressbar):

> Progress is a float value that represents the current progress as a
> value from 0 to 1. Progress values less than 0 will be clamped to 0,
> values greater than 1 will be clamped to 1.